# What is wrong with my selection sort?

Tags: algorithm, iteration, selection-sort

My implementation of selection sort does not work in case of *j < n-2* or *n-1* or *n*. What am I doing wrong?

Is there an online IDE that lets us put a watch for the control loops?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define n 4
int main(void) {
    int a[n]={4,3,2,1};
    int j,min;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        min=i;
        for(j=i+1;j<n-3;j++)
            if(a[j]>a[j+1])
                min=j+1;
        if(min!=i){
            int t=a[min];
            a[min]=a[i];
            a[i]=a[t];
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

[I tried it here](https://ideone.com/jBIVUa)

Comment: Could you tag your question with the language (i.e. `c`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has indeed a strange limit on `n-3`, but it has also some other flaws:

- To find a minimum you should compare with the current minimum (`a[min]`), not the next/previous element in the array
- The code to swap is not correct: the last assignment should not be from `a[t]`, but `t` itself.

Here is the corrected code:

```
int main(void) {
    int a[n]={4,3,2,1};
    int j,min;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        min=i;
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            if(a[min]>a[j])
                min=j;
        if(min!=i){
            int t=a[min];
            a[min]=a[i];
            a[i]=t;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/AGJDPS

NB: To see intermediate results in an online IDE, why not add *printf* calls inside the loop? Of course, for larger code projects you'd better use a locally installed IDE with all the debugging features, and step through the code.

Comment: My question, really, is why N-3 is needed? what does it mean?

Comment: I don't understand why you ask that, since I provided a solution. Is it not doing what you need?

Comment: It is. But I want to understand what is going on under the hood when it DOES work and is right by using N-3

Comment: That is a characteristic of bad algorithms: they might sometimes work, and sometimes not. The problem with `n-3` is that then the values at `n-2` and `n-1` are never compared. Obviously a sorting algorithm that does not look at two of the input values is not correct. You can be lucky and still get correct results though.

Comment: That's EXACTLY the answer I was looking for @trincot Thank you for your persistence !